# Android listview on item click into page viewer in next screen and swipe

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, swipe

I have a `listview` contain items Apple, Banana, Orange ...in second screen `activity`
when I click on particular item on  Apple it navigates to Details screen

here output has to appear like by clicking on --> Apple ..if I swipe page then banana  and for next swipe Orange

Apple-->Banana-->Orange

If I click on Banana -->then it has to appear like Banana then left swipe Apple ..and for right swipe...Orange.

So which item I clicked on(Banana) `listview` in second screen it has to appear on details screen and for left swipe previous list item and for right swipe next item in the list.

Banana-->for left swipe  Apple
      -->for right swipe Orange

If I click on Orange -->then it has to appear like  Orange then left swipe Banana ..and for next left swipe...Orange.
      Banana

Orange-->for left swipe Banana--->for next left swipe-->Apple

but am getting output like Apple-->Banana-->Orange  for all the cases of each item clicked on the `listview`....

```
public class SecondScreen extends Activity {
ListView listView;
LayoutInflater lay;
    MyApplication app; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yearlistss);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(SecondScreen.this,app.totalvalue));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2,
                long arg3) {        


            Intent detailIntent =new Intent(SecondScreen.this, Details.class);          

            startActivity(detailIntent);            
        }
    });

    }


public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            Context context = null;

            private ArrayList<String> temperList1;


            public MyAdapter(SecondScreen secondScreen, ArrayList<String> totalvalue) {

                this.temperList1 = totalvalue;

            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return temperList.size();


            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return temperList;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                View layout = null;


                TextView totalval = null;


                if (convertView == null) {

                    lay = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
                    layout = lay.inflate(R.layout.secondlist, null);


                    totalval = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.total);                  


                } else {
                    layout = convertView;
                }                       

                 totalval.setText("" + temperList1.get(position));

                return layout;
    }

        }





}









public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ArrayList<String> totalvalue  = new ArrayList<String>();

}







public class Details extends FragmentActivity{

    MyApplication app;
    ViewPager pager;
  MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;     
 public static int position ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);    
    app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();      
    pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm,app.totalvalue);   
      pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

  }



public static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private final  ArrayList<String> temperList;



    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> totalvalue ) {
         super(fm);
         this.temperList = totalvalue;
    }


    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return ThingFragment.newInstance((temperList.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){

    return temperList.size();

    }

     private static class ThingFragment extends Fragment {       
            private String name1;
         static ThingFragment newInstance(String string ) {

                ThingFragment f = new ThingFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("name",string );
                f.setArguments(args);

                return f;
            }



            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                name1 = getArguments().getString("name");
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
                TextView t = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.prodcutt);
                t.setText(""+ name1);
                return v;
        }

    }

}


}
```

Comment: doing the same not able to swipe can you help :( @arunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `OnItemClickListener` for your list of fruits you should pass the position of the selected fruit in the `Intent` so you can know in the details activity which fruit was clicked, something like this:

```
Intent detailIntent =new Intent(SecondScreen.this, Details.class);          
detailIntent.putExtra("fruitPosition", arg2);
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

Then in your details activity you would retrieve that number and position the `ViewPager` accordingly:

```
setContentView(R.layout.detail);    
app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();      
pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm,app.totalvalue);   
pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
Intent startIntent = getIntent();
int fruitPosition = startIntent.getIntExtra("fruitPosition", 0);
pager.setCurrentItem(fruitPosition);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replydetailIntent.putExtra("fruitPosition",listView.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)); i changed the line but getting same thing

Comment: @arunk There is no need for the `listView.getItemIdAtPosition(arg2)` use my code from the answer. Even after the changes you don't have the `ViewPager` at the correct positions? Can you check and see what is the value of `int fruitPosition` in the details activity? See what is the value for different fruits.

Comment: @arunk I'm interested in what you get for `fruitPosition` in the **details activity** when clicking various fruits in the first list.

Comment: @arunk If that is what you're using is incorrect. I've modified my answer, use it exactly as you see it. The first part with the `detailIntent` from my answer in your `OnItemClickListener` for the `ListView`(in there you only need the tree lines from my answer). Try it and see how it goes.

Comment: i am following this code only and even i need to do the same thing as in this question but i am getting errors this is my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891786/trying-to-swipe-deatiled-activity-obtained-from-listview-item-click-getting-null#comment20884704_14891786 can you help me?

Comment: @Luksprog after searching lot the only code similar to my question was this. so, following this can you help to achive my goal?